Build issues with docker image and Bun
I get permissions issue when I try to run this docker image.
FROM node:20.12.2 as build
RUN npm install -g bun@1.1.10
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN bun install --frozen-lockfile --prefer-offline
RUN npm run build

FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build ./bin /app/bin
CMD [ "/app/bin" ]

exec ./bin failed: Permission denied

is /app/bin really the command you want to run? that looks like it may be a directory rather than an executable

Try this before you execute the last line. RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app/bin"]
